# Performance of ng-repeat with dynamically generated array of data

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

Let's say I have an array of objects and that each object has a unique ID and a text property.

Now, let's say I have a `ng-repeat` like this one:

**Controller**

```
$scope.data = my_arr;
```

**View**

```
<div ng-repeat="for elem in data track by elem.id">
    {{ elem.text }}
</div>
```

Special note on the `track by`.

What would happen if I assigned a completely new array to the `data` variable (`$scope.data = new_arr;`), if the content of this new array:

- is completely identical to the previous one
- it contains 1 new element
- it contais all elements except 1

Will AngularJS be smart enough to:

- not re-render all `div` elements
- append/insert only the new `div` element to the DOM
- hide/delete only the `div` that isn't contained in the new array

Comment: Should the ng-repeat expression be "for elem in data track by elem.id"?

Comment: @slbteam08 Ah, yes, that is a typo, let me fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you’re using `track by elem.id`, Angular will reuse DOM elements. It will only add or remove one element to the document tree. Per [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat):

> Should you reload your data later, `ngRepeat` will not have to rebuild the DOM elements for items it has already rendered, even if the JavaScript objects in the collection have been substituted for new ones.

Comment: Yes, I'm concerned about this part: `if the JavaScript objects in the collection have been substituted for new ones.`. The thing is that this makes sense when you pull/push items from the same collection, but what would happen if the entire collection is changed? Hence, `$scope.data = new_arr;`

Comment: `ngRepeat` will check for matching ids and move / remove elements if needed, but will not remove an element then add it again for the same id.

Comment: Do you happen to know how could I test the rendering speed of `ng-repeat` (or pretty much any angular directive)?

Comment: And by "rendering speed" I mean the amount of time it takes from Angular detecting a change in the data set to the last operation related to actual rendering/DOM modifying.

Comment: I guess you could use Chrome Devtools to do this: https://addyosmani.com/blog/performance-optimisation-with-timeline-profiles/

Comment: How would I use that to measure the amount of time that has passed between Angular detecting a change and the end of the rendering? That would, if I understand correctly, allow me to measure only the rendering. And not very precisely.

Comment: Alright, as soon as this change is detected by Angular’s dirty-checking algorithm (wrap your code in a `$scope.$evalAsync` call if your change is async and not handled within Angular for this to be instant), Angular will compare ids and update DOM if needed. This part is dependant on your browser and a little bit out of scope :)